# Ionic 2 requests to Restul API

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this Ionic 2 app that has to connect to a restul api in order to get information (usual things, like get posts of users, send/receive password, ecc...).

In a situation in which both frontend and backend reside on the same machine, no problem, the backend can look for a token in the localStorage of the browser in order to see if the user is allowed to get the content. But in this situation, with a smartphone app and a server online, how does this communication thing work? I don't want users who know the API URL to see the JSONs, the password ecc...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is a broad question, but ideally you would want to implement oauth2 using a library or framework that supports it like [restify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth2-server-restify) or [django](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

Comment: Is it something I have to do client-side or server-side?

Comment: Well both! This is not trivial if that's what you're hoping for